# XAMPP Compatibility with Windows 10

Tags: windows, xampp

I would like to know if XAMPP is natively compatible with Windows 10 because on this site:

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Just mention in Requirements:

Windows 2008, 2012, Vista, 7, 8 (Important: XP or 2003 not supported)

however there is no citation regarding Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, XAMPP does work on Windows 10.